# 301 rewrite rule causes SEO alert

Tags: iis, https, seo, redirect, http-status-code-301

I use the following rewrtie rule to enforce visitors using HTTPS in my website. SEO check tools mark this redirection as a negative SEO parameter. How should I set 200 status code for redirecting to HTTPS or there is another way rather than redirection?

```
            <rule name="HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" negate="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

This is a sample report from sitechecker.pro :

> Page status code: 301 > 200
>
> The content and destination URL should deliver the
>   desired experience when clicked. Web crawlers can block pages that use
>   redirects.
>
> We recommend you promote a page with the 200 status code.

Comment: What status code does your browser get when requesting the page? And what platform is this? Apache?

Comment: I am not sure what is the SEO firendly response but I guess it should be 404. The platform is windows and IIS. @Machavity

Comment: The SEO tool you used is ridiculous here. Simply ignore that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with your rewrite. The response your "seo tool" returns seems to indicate your asking it to scan `http://example.com`? If that's the case that's a reasonable/expected result (and not an issue as http is not your sites preferred url). If you use the HTTPS url `https://example.com` I would expect your site would return a `200 OK` response - which should satisfy your seo tool?

Having a redirect from http to https or otherwise enforcing a single cannonical url (ie with or without www / all lowercase etc) is a good seo practise.

Redirects are bad for seo on your primary url `https://example.com` as they cause an additional request so delay page load (e.g. redirecting from `https://example.com/` to `https://example.com/home` Should be avoided) Also crawlers may dislike redirects in some cases as they can be used in "black hat" seo practises.